# angularJs custom directive not invoked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJs. I have created a simple custom directive in Angular to print out some text. The code is below:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demo-app', ['ngRoute']);
demoApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>Hello World!!</h1>'
  };
});
```

In the html file I am using it like below:

```
<hello-world/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo-app.js"></script>
```

I am not seeing the output "Hello World!". Please let me know where I am going wrong? I am using Angular 1.3 version.

Comment: please share with the js fiddle,plunker example, it is difficult to find the source of issue. Nevertheless, let me guess otherwise.

Comment: My bad. I did not refer to the app inside the "ng-app" attribute of the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

I did it following way in my project, and it is working fine.

**customDirective.js**

```
myApp.directive('viewTodoSuccessModal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/scripts/app-angular/directives/templates/view-todo-success-modal.html'
    };
});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myAppControllers'
  , 'myAppDirectives'
]);
```

included/referenced in html page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app-angular/app.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app-angular/Directives/CustomDirectives.js")"></script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether your module name is 'demo-app' in html or not.If it is not then make it correct.module name in script file should be same as html file.

```
<html ng-app="demo-app">  
 <head>    
   <script src="angular.js"></script>   
 </head>  
 <body>   
   <hello-world /> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
     angular.module('demo-app',[]);

     angular.module('demo-app')
      .directive('helloWorld', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<h1>Hello World!!</h1>'
        };
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/vSpR4/1/**